# how to add validation in gridview textbox?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_quantity" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"quantity") %>'>
        </asp:Label>

    </ItemTemplate>

    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtquantity" Width="90px" onkeypress="return validatenumerics(event);" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"quantity") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFquantity" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtquntity" Display="None" ErrorMessage="This field is required value" ValidationGroup="quantity">
        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="VCquantity" runat="Server" TargetControlID="RFquantity"/>

    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I want to shows an javascript message , if text box is empty..i tried this code. for validation purpose required field validation is added.then "edit" button is not fired..please help me.

This is my grid with edit ,update ,cancel and cancel button

```
  protected void gvproducts_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    gvproducts.EditIndex = -1;
    grid();

}
protected void gvproducts_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    gvproducts.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    grid();
}
protected void gvproducts_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{

    TextBox txtquantity = (TextBox)gvproducts.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Controls[1];

    int st = Convert.ToInt32(gvproducts.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString());


    objsupplyPL.quantity = Convert.ToInt32(txtquantity.Text.ToString());

    objsupplyPL.sno = st;
    DataTable scmpurchase = new DataTable();
    scmpurchase = objsupplyBAL.updatepurchase(objsupplyPL);

    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "UpdateDetails", "alert('Update Successful');", true);
    gvproducts.EditIndex = -1;
    grid();
}
```

Comment: can you show your edit button code ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a validator to the gridview textbox, created in edit-mode of a bound field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524296/adding-a-validator-to-the-gridview-textbox-created-in-edit-mode-of-a-bound-fiel)

Comment: I added my edit button code..

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is add a ValidationSummery with ShowMessageBox and a ValidationGroup just above the GridView

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" ShowMessageBox="true" ShowSummary="false" ValidationGroup="quantity" />
```

And change the TemplateField to this (make sure EnableClientScript=true) and make sure the EditButton has same validationgroup

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_quantity" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"quantity") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtquantity" Width="90px" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"quantity") %>' ValidationGroup="quantity"  />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFquantity" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtquantity" EnableClientScript="true"  Display="None" ErrorMessage="This field is required value" ValidationGroup="quantity" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>        
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ValidationGroup="quantity" />
```

Comment: I added validation summary as you like...but it's not effect edit button

Comment: How does your EditButton declaration looks like?

Answer (score 1):

just add a class to your `TextBox` and find the control using class finder with jquery. Then, you can check whether the `TextBox.val()` is empty or not using the javascript function.